# После установки линукса(Pop!_OS), он не запускается

Tags: linux

Где-то под конец лета 2020-го решил себе установить линукс, но чтобы легче было переходить, ставил паралельно с виндой. Друг поповетовал Pop OS, и поставил его на мой старый ноутбук, но там не работали драйвера нвидии, а играть я все же хотел. Помучавшись несколько дней, я забросил дело найти драйвера, и забил. Потом мне купили новый ноутбук на дн, и я решил опять попробовать свои силы. Но теперь идёт уже с пол года череда неудач: сначала все ставилось нормально, но потом при первом запуске был просто пустой экран, и даже терминал не запускался. Потом запускался лишь раз, а после ребута снова так зависал. То вообще с флешки поп ос не запускалась, а зависала на Started session 1 of user. Потом я вставил в другой usb-разьем, и флешка запустилась, но после перезапуска в линукс, опять черный экран. Я уже пробовал с разных флешек ставить, в биосе Secure boot отключен, вообще хз, что делать. В общей сложности я уже где-то раз 15-20 за эти пол года пробовал установить поп ос, и каждый раз случался один из этих вариантов. Пробовал и Clean install, снося винду, и дуал бутом, и менять кучу всего в биосе. Вот последний раз: с одного usb-разьема все зависало на Started session 1 of user, с другого я установил линукс.
Во время установки я просто кликал далее, только разметку диска сделал сам: boot efi 600Mb, root 20Gb и остальное где-то из 380Gb на home. Есть два диска: SSD, HDD, на ссд винда, на 400GB с всего 1000Gb с хдд ставил линукс. После установки перезапустил ноут — просто серый экран, ctrl+alt+f1/f2/f3... не работали. Второй перезапуск: все время кликаю ctrl+alt+f2 — переходит в выбор между Pop os и Pop os recovery, выбираю Pop os — дальше кликаю ctrl+alt+f2 — переходит на черный(не серый, как раньше) экран с подчеркивающим знаком(я типа в терминале), но через секунд 5-10 подчеркивание исчезло и опять все зависло, как в прошлый раз, но теперь экран черный. Всё время ставлю pop os с nvidia драйверами, потому что сам ставить драйвера я пробовал, и то систему ломал, то просто ничего не выходило. Ну такое. Ноут - Dell G3 3590. Если кто-то поможет - буду очень благодарен. Извините, что текст такой большой, просто не умею писать кратко и хочу передать все, что может помочь.

Comment: Я, возможно, предложу трудный путь, но как насчет установки простой *советской* убунты?

Comment: Извините, но ваш вопрос выглядит как "компьютер не работает, что делать?", только в развёрнутой форме. Если вы не можете провести никакую диагностику (что совершенно нормально, я сам не всегда могу), то здесь вам вряд ли помогут при всём желании. Наверное единственное что тут можно посоветовать - это другой дистрибутив, больше подходящий новичкам, например Mint, Xubuntu или Windows. Если с другими ОС у вас будут те же проблемы, то это уже совсем другой, более общий вопрос, на который вам может быть и смогут ответить.

Comment: Кажется, диагностику проводить я не умею. А pop os я как раз выбрал потому, что там сразу шли нвидиа драйверы, и мне не надо было бы с ними париться. А если я поставлю какой-то другой линукс, то все будет сложнее.

Comment: Но попробую установить что-то другое поставить